# Does Prowler's helm effect makes an unblockable creature blockable by walls?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Full question in title. Do equipment effects always override creature effects even tho the creature effects are superior?

Comment: The "full question" in your title is a different question than the one in your description text - whether equipments in general override creature's effects is entirely different from the question of the specific effects named here.

Comment: I think this question may be labouring under some unclear or mistaken assumptions: that "creature effects are superior" (the rules don't define anything like that, so I don't know what you mean), that Prowler's Helm "overrides creature effects", that the Prowler's Helm wording means "can be blocked by walls". I suggest you ask about specifics, rather than try to extract a generalised principle, given the generalised principle you're asking about appears to be based on notions not consistent with the game's rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be asking about a creature with

> [This creature] can't be blocked.

equipped with a [Prowler's Helm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProwler%27s%5d%2b%5bHelm%5d) that has

> Equipped creature can't be blocked except by Walls.

Each of these abilities creates a blocking restriction, and all blocking restrictions must be obeyed.

> 509.1b The defending player checks each creature he or she controls to see whether it’s affected by any restrictions (effects that say a creature can’t block, or that it can’t block unless some condition is met). If any restrictions are being disobeyed, the declaration of blockers is illegal. [...]

So that means it's can't be blocked by any creature, and it can't be blocked by non-Wall creatures. The result is that it can't be blocked by any creature.

Answer (score 0):

In Magic, **can't** always wins from **can**.

The creature says:

> [This creature] can't be blocked.

The [Prowler's Helm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProwler%27s%5d%2b%5bHelm%5d) says:

> Equipped creature can't be blocked except by Walls.

This will simply result in:

> Can't be blocked

The prowlers helm doesn't add anything.

Comment: You misread Prowler. It doesn't give walls the ability to block. It takes away the ability of non-walls to block. So that means you have two "can't" (restrictions). It comes down CR 509.1b, not CR 101.2.